# How to automatically create triggers in a new spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I want to do is:

- Create a new spreadsheet using Google Apps Script
- Create a trigger for this newly created spreadsheet

Here is my code:

```js
function createfile() {
    var timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
    var tempStartDate = new Date();
    tempStartDate.setDate(tempStartDate.getDate() + 21); 
    var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(tempStartDate, timezone, 'yyMMdd');

    var tempEndDate= new Date();
    tempEndDate.setDate(tempEndDate.getDate()+26);
    var endDate= Utilities.formatDate(tempEndDate, timezone, 'yyMMdd');

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('123123123123123C3Znd64gFUvGnpCLTbr54s');

    //Make a copy of the template file
    var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('123123123123123C3Znd64gFUvGnpCLTbr54s').makeCopy().getId();

    //Rename the copied file
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('testaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' + startDate+'-'+endDate );
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('monday')
    .timeBased()
    .everyHours(6)
    .create();
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or can you provide some logs maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### There is no way to do that on a sheet

Triggers are limited and you cannot make a time based trigger attached to a spreadsheet. You can attach other triggers to other spreadsheets such as `onEdit` but not a clock trigger.

Time based triggers are attached to a *script*.

[image]

Also, a script can only create a time-based trigger for *itself*, not another script.

[image]

You might think that you can make a new script from another script, and there is an API for that, the Apps Script API. However, the API does *not* allow you to create triggers with it.

So, unfortunately, there is no way to create a copy of a project and then add a trigger to it completely from a different script. There will always be some manual operations involved. You can copy it, but to initialize the trigger, you would need to run the function from *within* the copy.

#### References

- [ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)
- [SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder)
- [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api)
- [Manage script projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/manage-projects)
- [Executing Apps Script Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/samples/execute)